# Circuits/breakers for new one bedroom suite - CEC

Tags: electrical, wiring, construction

Anyone care to review and comment on my proposed electrical circuits for a new detached suite I am building. 125 amp main. 600 sq ft.

Standard 2 pole:

- 50 amp stove
- 30 amp water heater
- 20 amp heat pump
- 20 amp heaters

Single pole standard:

- 15 amp lights down and outside
- 15 amp lights upstairs

AFCI:

- 20 amp kitchen1
- 20 amp kitchen2
- 15 amp dishwasher
- 15 amp refrigerator
- 20 amp microwave
- 20 amp receptacles, whole house and exterior

Comment: Is your goal to spend the absolute least money to be barely compliant with the law, or do you want the space to be practical and livable? We can't go by breakers, what is the total wattage of the heaters going to actually be?

Comment: We have a budget for sure. however, i am doing the work myself so can afford to spend a bit more on materials if it makes sense. I've sized the breakers based on the appliances. heaters are 3x 900watt, 240vac. 3.75amp.

Comment: Are you going to have undercounter lights in the kitchen? If so you may need an outlet under the sink for the LED driver, and your only code-complaint option there is to utilize the dishwasher circuit or run another dedicated circuit. Most inspectors would prefer to see a dedicated but taking from the dishwasher is CEC complaint.

Comment: Another reason for an outlet in the sink cabinet is for fancy kitchen sink faucets that have features like touch on-off — and there even models now that are hooked up to Alexa and can dispense exact amounts of water: “Alexa dispense one cup of water in the kitchen”. Those faucets prefer to be plugged in though they can run off of batteries.

Comment: Yeah, NEC is not a design guide, it is "less than this and the house is not even habitable" so it's an anti-slumlord measure.  (the aim is to reduce extension cord use due to inadequate outlets).  Circuits and outlets should be design to serve the occupants' needs. Electricity is our servant, it works for us.

Comment: You appear to have completely forgotten about the bathroom. That needs **at least** one dedicated circuit.

Comment: It looks very close for that small residential place. With the exception of laundry and bathroom this is close to a apprentice question , with the exceptions that motor loads like refrigerators would never be on an AFCI ? Why they are motor loads , kitchen 1/2 are GFCI’s . Ok done don’t want embarrass non pros but there are 4-6 others GFCI and actual load vs amps. Pick one or the other.